How to Unlink Section Headers
I have been working on a document with the Google Docs API that contains many different sections, I would like to have a different header for every section. In a document you can manually do this by going to the section's header and unchecking "Link to Previous"

I was wondering if there was a way to do this through the API
I have tried adding a header to the section through the API like this:
    let resource = {
      "requests": [
        {"createHeader": {
            "sectionBreakLocation": {"index": sectionBreakIndex},
            "type": "DEFAULT"
          }
        }
      ]
    }

   Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, documentId);


But this results in a 500 error no matter what index I put
Any help would be appreciated
